# C# Class Definitions - Which Keyword?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Question]

I'm not entirely sure about this. Is it '`static`'?

Comment: Please dont post images but the code as (formatted) text.

Answer (score 4):

The keyword you're looking for is `partial`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Yes partial is needed, but you also need abstract on the methods and the classes or it still won't compile because non-abstract methods must declare a body.

Comment: You're right. You need more than one keyword to make it compile. 'partial' by itself won't cut it, neither will 'abstract'. The question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No It's not static. [You need Partial Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx). Also You need to provide body to your functions.

> It is possible to split the definition of a class or a struct, an
>   interface or a method over two or more source files. Each source file
>   contains a section of the type or method definition, and all parts are
>   combined when the application is compiled.

To split a class definition, use the partial keyword modifier.

See Below example:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```